# React Native renders a blank screen with no errors in terminal, i've included code below , please assist, i can seem to figure out why this happens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

- please review code below , from what i can see it should all be correct*
- im using Mac osx 10.10.5*

I am learning react-native

This app has two buttons; increment and decrement that call actions on the counter and the counter value re-renders.

```
import React from 'react';
    import {Text, Button, View} from 'react-native';
    import {useState} from 'react';
    
    function CounterScreen({navigation}) {
    
    CounterScreen = () =>{
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState (0);
    
    return (
    
   
//Code to create counter on click


 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' , background: '#81B214'}} >
    
    <Button color='green'
             title='Add'
             onPress={() => {setCounter(counter + 1);}}
             />
    
    <Button color='red'
     title='remove'
     onPress={()=> {setCounter(counter - 1);}}
     />;
    
     <Text style={{color:'white',
         fontWeight:600,
        fontSize:50}}> 
        Basket Count: {counter}
    </Text>;
    
    <Button title="Go Home" 
    onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Home')}
    />;
            
     </View>
    
        
        );
    };
    };
    
    export default CounterScreen;
```

Comment: Your code looks really messy. Can you clean it up a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Text, Button, View } from "react-native"

const CounterScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  return (
    //Code to create counter on click

    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        background: "#81B214",
      }}
    >
      <Button
        color="green"
        title="Add"
        onPress={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1)
        }}
      />
      <Button
        color="red"
        title="remove"
        onPress={() => {
          setCounter(counter - 1)
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: 600, fontSize: 50 }}>
        Basket Count: {counter}
      </Text>
      <Button title="Go Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default CounterScreen
```

Comment: thanks Nikhil , but it still renders a blank screen.. im rewriting the code with a reducer instead to see if that makes any change

Answer (score 0):

it should be backgroundColor not background

and convert counter to string
Basket Count: {String(counter)}

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-34Z17zBCWY2e3D7i1Z-V1Z8RkxW32qI/view?usp=sharing

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Text, Button, View } from "react-native"

const CounterScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  return (
    //Code to create counter on click

    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#81B214",
      }}
    >
      <Button
        color="green"
        title="Add"
        onPress={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1)
        }}
      />
      <Button
        color="red"
        title="remove"
        onPress={() => {
          setCounter(counter - 1)
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: 600, fontSize: 50 }}>
        Basket Count: {String(counter)}
      </Text>
      <Button title="Go Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default CounterScreen
```